# What's a single word for someone who writes literature?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

As the title suggests, what's a single word to  call someone who writes literature?
(By Literature, I refer to great works such as those written by Keats, Joyce, Faulkner, Bronte, etc.)

Exempli gratia, we call someone who writes poetry a *poet*, a *playwright* writes drama etc. So, in general, what do we call someone who writes literature?

(Mathematician+Physicist+Chemist+...)=Scientist

Then, (Poet+Playwright+...)=?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** By literature, I mean fictional works such as poetry, play, short-story, novel. Science fiction can also be considered. Some Feynman-esque papers might suffice to fall in the category. Although it excludes text books, scientific papers and the equivalent.

Comment: What is wrong with [writer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/writer)?

Comment: @Yay Writer is more generalized. It doesn't necessarily involve writing literature.

Comment: @Sayantan Santra: One problem is that "great' and 'literature' are matters of opinion, so that there is no neutral word that will encompass only your idea of what constitutes 'literature'.  'Author' includes everyone who writes.

Comment: @jamesqf Your logic is correct. But, I think I've found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest, [***litterateur/littérateur***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=litt%C3%A9rateur%2Clitterateur%2Cliterator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clitt%C3%A9rateur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitterateur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliterator%3B%2Cc0)

> *Also*, **literator** *n.* - One who is devoted to the study or writing of literature [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/litt%C3%A9rateur)

Alternately, how about ***belletrist*** and ***literarian***?

> **belletrist**: a writer of belles-lettres [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/belletrist)
>
> **literarian** *n.* — «A literarian is someone who loves literature so much that he or she wants to share it with as many people as possible, so this award is for those who dedicate their lives to love of literature.» —“Taking on the establishment made [Ferlinghetti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Ferlinghetti) a shoo-in to receive first-ever literarian award” by Heidi Benson San Francisco Chronicle (California) Nov. 16, 2005. (source: Double-Tongued Dictionary) [A Way with Words](http://www.waywordradio.org/literarian_1/)
>
> An educated or lettered person; one engaged in literary pursuits. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais/literarian)
>
> *James Patterson honored with 2015 Literarian Award* [National Book Foundation](http://www.nationalbook.org/literarian.html#.Vsh9fIe9KSM)

Comment: Nice one. Was hoping something like this. I'm gonna wait a while, see if someone can suggest something better. Else, I'll definitely accept your answer.

Comment: Both of these words are essentially not used compared to [author or writer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=litt%C3%A9rateur%2Clitterateur%2Cauthor%2Cwriter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clitt%C3%A9rateur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitterateur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauthor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwriter%3B%2Cc0), so I wouldn't consider them idiomatic English. Which may be fine depending on how the OP wants to use them.

Answer (score 14):

I might have misinterpreted your intentions, but I was surprised no one suggested simply **[author](http://tfd.com/author)**:

> One who practices writing as a profession.

Comment: because author could also describe someone who merely writes a paper or article? He mentioned Literature.

Comment: @Gandalf - Except that it takes far more than a single word to define the meaning that a given person assigns to "literature".

Comment: The writer of a text book in biology can be called an author. But that's not literature.

Comment: @SayantanSantra Sure it is, in fact "the literature" is a common phrase referring to all the relevant academic writings on a topic.

Comment: @HotLicks That's why I was saying "author" is not sufficient.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't mean 'literature' in that context.

Comment: @SayantanSantra Well no one here is a mind reader, so you're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: @curiousdannii You're welcome to suggest an edit.

Comment: @SayantanSantra I can't suggest an edit because you still haven't explained what you mean by the word.

Comment: @SayantanSantra Do you mean "Literature" like William Faulkner or James Joyce or Somerset Maugham? If that is your intention than I can do the edit for you...otherwise you need to get more specific.

Comment: Ie, not pulp fiction, sci fi etc (a use of the word literature that is of very dubious value.)

Comment: @Gandalf Yes. And also like Shakespeare and Keats.

Comment: @curiousdannii I think readers of Jules Verne, Ray Bradbury, Arthur C Clarke, H G Wells, Kurt Vonegut, Thomas Pynchon, etc. might take except to that!

Comment: @SayantanSantra Shakespeare wrote plays and sonnets.

Comment: @Gandalf I take exception to it too! But there are lots of people who refuse to allow any sci-fi to be classified as "literature" - for many people it basically means "the superior writings which I happen to like and btw your favourite authors aren't sophisticated enough to be included"

Comment: @curiousdanii 'literature' (things like fiction, poetry, plays) is different from 'the literature' (which is used in the context of research, primarily non-fiction articles)

Answer (score 6):

When people use the word *writer*, they are typically referring to someone who writes creative works of literature, like what you have described.

*Writer* encapsulates poet, playwright, novelist, etc, perfectly.

People who solely write non-creative things are not termed *writers*: they might be called *copywriters*, *journalists*, *textbook writers* or even *manual writers*, etc.

Likewise, if a speaker wanted to refer to a broad set of people who wrote, and they wanted to include those that do not write literature such as I have mentioned above, they would not use the term *writers* on its own. They might say, *all of those whose job it is to write*, or some equivalent phrase which makes it clear that they are referring to a broader group than just *writers*, because that term really does mean writer of *literature*.

If someone described themselves as a *writer* and it subsequently transpired that the sum total of their writing consisted of, say, writing technical manuals for the aerospace industry, I would say that they were being disingenuous to the point of being downright deceitful.

Therefore, I'm sure that it's the term that you're looking for (irrespective of the fact that you are already aware of it).

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

***[Man of letters](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/man-of-letters):***

> - a man, usually a ​writer, who ​knows a lot about ​literature

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Literatus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literatus):*** (formal)

> ( singular noun, plural *literati*)
>
> - person of scholarly or literary attainments; intellectual.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: I was hoping a single word.

Comment: And also something that includes women???

Comment: @Mynamite That'll be better. Yes.

Comment: @Josh61 - You may add the following example to your answer:  *Maurice Baring (1874 – 1945) was an English man of letters, known as a dramatist, poet, novelist, translator and essayist, and also as a travel writer and war correspondent*.

Answer (score 4):

@Charon has explained well why **writer** is in fact the real answer to your question. But if you want something more, try:

### [Wordsmith](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordsmith)

> a person who works with words; especially :  a skillful writer; an expert in the use of words.
>
> a fluent and prolific writer, especially one who writes professionally.

Depending upon what the person writes, the titles can become specific such as novelist, satirist, lyricist etc. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writer) for explanation.

Comment: Really interesting one.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure what you meant by **literature**. To me **literature** is a general word for everything formally written.

Comment: Journalism is not usually considered literature, but journalists are wordsmiths.

Comment: @Mitch Journalism is literature in a hurry. - Mathew Arnold

Comment: @NVZ Well said!

Answer (score -3):

How about literatuate? I think that's workable though cannot find exact dictionary meaning

Comment: Is it even a word?

Comment: Stick to "literary figure"

Comment: That wasn't desired. I needed valid English words (ie. included in a reputed dictionary).