# Is there a *single* word that describes the act of "creative writing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Greetings English Language Boffins! 
I'm looking for a *single* word that describes the act of "***creative* writing**" 
or the person who is a creative writing author?

I've been trying to think & google for it, but so far no luck. 
Noted this Q/A: [One word in describing a person who always trying to be creative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388107/one-word-in-describing-a-person-who-always-trying-to-be-creative) 
which is *similar*, but I'm looking for a word that is *specific* to writing. 
Hope you can help!

Comment: Have you thought about ***fiction***?

Comment: @Jim good, succinct word. (thanks!) Fiction is a _subset_ of creative writing and  if the type of writing we were doing was limited to that genre, it would be perfect. I'm actually writing a non-fiction book and hoping to capture the essence of the activity in a single word. I know it's a bit of a stretch but was hoping the StackExchange community would have better vocab than me. ;-)

Comment: @nelsonic That would depend on whether we are talking about the written or the act of writing.  And either way, there is more to creative writing than fiction:  poetry may be fictional, but far from most of it is.

Comment: @Tuffy agreed. I've attempted to clarify the question. (though as a "beginner" I feel increasingly unwelcome on StackExchange. my question was "down voted" without any clarification as to _why_ the question was unsuitable ... :-( I don't understand what is "wrong" with asking for help finding a word ...)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308575/whats-a-single-word-for-someone-who-writes-literature . This may help ; consider the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: @Specter thanks for sharing. quite a few words/options in that thread! 

Answer (score 3):

There is no single word for the expression *creative writing*.  This is because it arose in the post war period, largely in connection with with education and above all in relation to the teaching of English in schools in the anglophone world.

Historically, most writing in English lessons concentrated on exercises of dictation,  comprehension, paraphrase and précis.  Essays came later, either on ethical and historical topics or as interpretation or appreciation of some work of literature.

The idea that that children should express themselves by writing their own poems or stories, grew early in the twentieth and became increasingly established after 1945, reaching its zenith in the 1960s.  But it was never given a name.

There is a general term for writing:  ***LITERATURE*** and in days gone by writers were often described as *men of letters* (ignoring, of course, in those times, the existence of female writers).

But ***literature*** will not really do.  It is true that the ‘English Literature’ taught to British schoolchildren would cover the **content** of what is generally understood by *creative writing*.  But it does not involve students in creating anything.

No novelist, playwright or poet known to me has ever claimed the title of *creative* *writer*.

***Creative writing*** is a well established term.  Everyone knows what you mean if you tell them you are taking a creative writing course.  It doesn’t take long to type.  If you want to shorten it for. tweet, try *CW*.  Acronyms are very popular.

Comment: +1; per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_writing), `... creative writing is a more contemporary and process-oriented name for what has been traditionally called literature, including the variety of its genres.`

Comment: @Tuffy thanks for the insightful background on origins of creative writing. 

Answer (score -1):

Nope, not so far as I know. If there was one, every English department of every university would be using it to describe their creative writing courses. But no, they're all just called 'creative writing'. Dull, huh?

Comment: thanks for getting involved. It's a shame that StackExchange does not reward "No" answers ... I suspect that _most_ schools & universities use the two-word form (a) because they haven't gone searching for a more concise alternative, and (b) the longer form _sounds_ more involved/distinctive than just "writing". Perhaps that _is_ the best way of referring to it? ;-)